# Bootstrapped GCC is using incorrect search paths

Tags: gcc, qnx, gcc10

I'm attempting to build GCC 10.5 for an older version of QNX on an x86 platform in an Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64 environment. I downloaded the `gcc-10.5.0.tar.xz` file from GNU's FTP server and ran the following commands:

```bash
tar -xvf gcc-10.5.0.tar.xz
cd gcc-10.5.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir bin-qnx63-i386
cd bin-qnx63-i386
./../gcc-10.5.0/configure $(options)
make
```

These are the current options in `$(options)`:

- `--host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`
- `--target=i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0`
- `--prefix=/usr/local/nyab`
- `--program-prefix=nyab-`
- `--disable-multilib`
- `--enable-threads=posix`
- `--enable-tls`
- `--enable-version-specific-runtime-libs`
- `--enable-languages=c,c++`
- `--disable-libada`
- `--disable-libgm2`
- `--enable-default-pie`
- `--enable-werror`
- `--enable-checking`
- `--enable-valgrind-annotations`
- `--with-sysroot=/opt/qnx630/target/qnx6`

In addition, I've copied `ar`, `as`, `ld` and `ranlib` from the SDK to `/usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/bin` as directed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html#Building-a-cross-compiler). After an initial failed run, I copied the CRT libraries from the SDK to `/usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/lib` as that appeared to be needed as well.

This setup seems to work until I get to the `i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/libstdc++-v3` directory where it fails. Looking at `config.log` the issue seems to stem from the following line:

`/usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/bin/ld: cannot open /opt/qnx630/target/qnx6x86/lib/crtbegin.o: No such file or directory`

The correct path is `/opt/qnx630/target/qnx6/x86/lib`.

I've attempted to modify the `--with-sysroot` option to include trailing slashes, but that seems to have no effect. Next, I created a small C file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I passed it to the compiler using the flags of the failing command plus the flag to spit out additional information (formatted for StackOverflow):

```
/home/nyab/gcc/bin-qnx63-i386/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/nyab/gcc/bin-qnx63-i386/./gcc/ \
    -B/usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/bin/ \
    -B/usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/lib/ \
    -isystem /usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/include \
    -isystem /usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/sys-include \
    -v -o /tmp/test -g -O2 /tmp/test.c
```

And found that GCC is creating the incorrect paths (newlines added for the incorrect paths):

```
...
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-B' '/home/nyab/gcc/bin-qnx63-i386/./gcc/' '-B' '/usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/bin/' '-B' '/usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/lib/' '-isystem' '/usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/include' '-isystem' '/usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/sys-include' '-v' '-o' '/tmp/test' '-g' '-O2' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 /home/nyab/gcc/bin-qnx63-i386/./gcc/collect2 -V -Y P,

/opt/qnx630/target/qnx6x86/lib

 -Qy -m i386nto --dynamic-linker /usr/lib/ldqnx.so.2 -o /tmp/test /usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/lib/crt1.o /usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/lib/crti.o

/opt/qnx630/target/qnx6x86/lib/crtbegin.o

 -L/home/nyab/gcc/bin-qnx63-i386/./gcc -L/usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/bin -L/usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/lib /tmp/ccb1wUOU.o -lgcc -lc -lgcc /usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/lib/crtend.o /usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/lib/crtn.o
...
```

I have confirmed `crtbegin.o` is in `/usr/local/nyab/i386-pc-nto-qnx6.3.0/lib` although it was copied from `/opt/qnx630/target/qnx6/x86/lib`. Does anyone know where I went wrong or what to try next?

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at QNX's patches to the gcc build tree to find out if there was anything they needed to change to make their build system work.   The sources are posted on their community website here: http://community.qnx.com/viewvc/tools/gcc/?root=core-dev-tools&system=exsy1011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

Modify `SYSROOT_SUFFIX_SPEC` in `<src-dir>/gcc/config/i386/nto.h` to `/86`.

**Long answer**

GCC uses [spec files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) to determine how to call itself and other programs with their appropriate command line arguments. Thorough investigation of `<src-dir>/gcc/gcc.c` will show you how these files are created or read in to the program. Since we fail during linker invocation, the `LINK_SPEC` definition matters here. For this QNX build, its found in `<src-dir>/gcc/config/i386/nto.h`. The two lines that matter are:

```
...
   %{!YP,*:%{p:-Y P,%R/lib} \
    %{!p:-Y P,%R/lib}} \
...
```

The spec language reference linked earlier says `%R` is "the concatenation of target_system_root and target_sysroot_suffix." The `target_sysroot_suffix` is actually defined in the `nto.h` file under the `SYSROOT_SUFFIX_SPEC` preprocessor macro. Cross referencing this definition with other definitions in `mti-linux.h` and `st.h`, the specification in `nto.h` is missing the forward slash at the beginning. Changing the value from `x86` to `/x86` will get you past this issue.